Linear combinations of special square matrices to receive certain output matrices
The following question is one I asked 3 years ago on MathOverflow:
Linear combinations of special matrices
Since I am still interested in an answer I would like to post it here too. Before I state the problem here are my main questions:

Is this problem in the computer science literature known?
Does anyone have an ideas for an efficient constructing algorithm?

Example of the problem:
In the case n = 2 (dimension of the square matrices) I have the following 3 input matrices:
Inputs
X1           X2           X3     
1 0    and   0 1    and   0 1
1 0          0 1         -1 0

If I linear-combine them correctly (X1 + X3) and (X2 - X3) I can get the 2 output matrices:
Outputs
M1           M2
1 1    and   0 0
0 0          1 1

Goal and rules
The goal is to get all n output matrices where each row is filled with 1s using as few input matrices as possible. The first output-matrix should have the first row filled with ones (other cells 0). And the second output-matrix has the second row filled with ones, and so on...
The rules are, each input matrix may have at most one nonzero value per row.
I have a recursive algorithm with the recurrence equation T(n) = 3*T(n) + O(n). This leads to less than O(n²) input matrices. But I would like to be close to O(n)*log(n).
Example for n=3 using 6 inputs (Edit: 17.08.2024)
INPUT 1
   1   0   0
   1   0   0
   1   0   0

INPUT 2
   0   1   0
   0   1   0
   0   1   0

INPUT 3
   0   0   1
   0   0   1
   0   0   1

INPUT 4
   0  -1   0
   0   0   1
   0   0   0

INPUT 5
  -1   0   0
   0   0   0
   0   0   1

INPUT 6
   0   0   0
  -1   0   0
   0   1   0

LINEAR COMBINATIONS
OUTPUT 1 =   0   0   1  -1  -1   0
OUTPUT 2 =   0   1   0   1   0  -1
OUTPUT 3 =   1   0   0   0   1   1


In general, you're going to need n² input matrices, just because it takes n² equations to determine the values of n² unknowns.  Note that your problem is unchanged by making your inputs and outputs into vectors of length n², so all of the many algebraic methods (like Gaussian elimination) for solving systems of equations applies.

I disagree. Die above example shows 3 Inputs for the case n = 2 which ist smaller (3 < 2²). You can create from the above case a recursive version this would result in 9 Inputs for n = 4 (9 < 4²) or 27 inputs for n = 8 (27 < 8²).... and so on. The algorithm has some similarities to karatsuba algotrihm link which has approx. n^1,58 "inputs" (in that case multiplications)

The example is convenient.  Try it with random ints.  I missed the "at most one nonzero value per row" on the first read, but I don't think that helps.
